# I have some problems understanding the problem

Tags: matrices

So I came across a problem which asks for the (1, 2, 3) × (3, 2, 1). What is the name of this operation?
I thought that this was a matrix but afterwards I realised that I cannot solve it this way.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "I have some problems understanding the problem" says nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, it refers to the "cross product". Given vectors $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $w =(w_1,w_2,w_3)$, then
$$
v \times w = (v_2 w_3 - v_3 w_2 , v_3 w_1 -  v_1 w_3 , v_1 w_2 - v_2 w_1 )
$$
or, in a format easier to memorize,
$$
v \times w = \left| \begin{matrix}
\hat \imath & \hat \jmath & \hat k \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 \end{matrix} \right|
$$
More information is available on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: oh get it, thanks so much!